# how to use Django's Date on year

Tags: django, model

I am new to Django. My question is this:

There is a field in my model, that is just a string of year. But I search Django's document and I do not find such a Django model's Field.And I do not want to define it with **CharField**, and **DateField** is too redundant to use.

How do I do it? Thanks.

Comment: Isn't a year an integer?

Comment: Why not just use a `PositiveSmallIntegerField`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/fields/#positivesmallintegerfield

Comment: Ok, maybe this is a good solution. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could add a place for choice like this? It isnt a char/date field but a proper year field only. The user can only select the years you have mentioned in YEAR_CHOICES

```
YEAR_CHOICES = ((1, '2012'),
                    (2, '2013'),
                    (3, '2014'))

class MyModel(models.Model):
    year = models.IntegerField(choices=YEAR_CHOICES)
```